# CLLocationManager delegates still called even after the viewcontroller it is in was popped

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have a viewcontroller that I will push and pop at many occassions, I noticed that the CLLocationManager instance is still there even after the viewcontroller is popped.

How should I fix this problem?

I am using swift but I found that the objects are still there even after the ViewController is popped.

any though?

Answer (score 0):

When you hit Back button, set CLLocationManager Delegate value to 'nil' in following function.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    //Set Delegate to nil here...
}
```